# tmux bind-key save output

Tags: tmux

I'd like to have a custom `tmux` bind-key to save screen output to a unique file.

This works

`bind-key S capture-pane -S -99999 \; save-buffer /tmp/tmux.txt \; delete-buffer`

but these do not, with and without escaping the `$` and parentheses.

`bind-key S capture-pane -S -99999 \; save-buffer $(mktemp --suffix=.txt) \; delete-buffer`

`bind-key S capture-pane -S -99999 \; save-buffer $(date +'/tmp/tmux-%s.txt') \; delete-buffer`

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$()` is evaluated by the shell so you need to run it as a shell command:

```
bind-key S capture-pane -S -99999 \; run-shell 'tmux save-buffer $(date +"/tmp/tmux-%s.txt")' \; delete-buffer
```

The important part is:

```
run-shell 'tmux save-buffer $(date +"/tmp/tmux-%s.txt")'
```

This will start a shell, expand the `$(date..)` command and then tell tmux to save the buffer to this file.